# How do you use the Discord API to find server member count for OTHER servers?

Tags: python, server, discord

How would i use python to find the server count for other servers? One's I'm not a part of? I can figure it out for my own, but not for others.

Comment: "I can figure it out for my own, but not for others." Unfortunately, you're right.

Comment: The bot must be in the server (with permissions) to access the guild data.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to have the server's guild ID for this. You can then fetch the guild from the discord API using [`fetch_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_guild) and then access the guild's [`member_count` attribute](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Guild).

```py
async def get_guild_members(guild_id: int):
    guild = bot.fetch_guild(guild_id)
    
    return guild.member_count
```